# How to get a university to make an admission decision more quickly

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I received an admit from University A with an acceptance deadline of March 22nd. But my top choice is University B, which—according to their website—won't get back to me until the end of March. I definitely want to join B if possible, but the timing on A means I may not even have heard back from B before A's deadline passes. Is there anything I can do to speed up B's getting back to me?

Answer (score 2):

Universities are aware of this problem. I suggest you either email or call the admissions office at both universities and tell them exactly what you said above, without naming the other university. For the first, ask for an extension for acceptance. For the second, ask whether they can inform you ahead of time about your application. They may or may not be sympathetic to your problem, but at least you'll have tried everything. Do note that if both universities simply say, "sorry to hear that, but we cannot do anything different," you will simply have to make a decision with limited information. Best of luck!